# Are there any fastlane actions or plugins that allow you to execute scripts between tests?

Tags: xctest, fastlane

I've searched quite a bit today but have not found any solid yes or no.

I'd like to know are there any plugins or actions for fastlane that allow you to execute a shell script between each test execution.

The reason I ask is that, while testing I spin up a server locally with docker. 
I'd like to be able to either clear this servers queues or tear it down and recreate between tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a fastlane plugin [test_center](https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/fastlane-plugin-test_center) that will allow you to provide a callback that is called between "test runs".

If you set the `:batch_count` parameter to the number of tests you want to run, the callback will be called after each batch.

That would allow you to make a shell call to docker to tear it down and spin it back up again.